# Save Field Names in Microsoft SQL Query Analyzer

Tags: sql-server, query-analyzer, field-names

When you save the results of a SQL query using "Microsoft SQL Query Analyzer" (version 8), the results of the query are saved but the column headers (field names) are not.  Any idea how to save the field names to the results file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always switch to "Results In Text" and you get the column headings, but no CSV

Comment: "Results in Text" give a tab delimited file which works too.  Thanks.